# UDP communication with some interface (using UDP Echo sample code, problem with main.m)

Tags: iphone, interface, udp, xib, program-entry-point

I´ve downloaded the UDPEcho sample code from Apple to make a simple UDP "connection" with a device.. I´m able to make a "connection" setting the ip and port of my device on the main.m provided. Analyzing my console i´m even getting a positive response from  the device from everything i´m sending from main.m.

My problem is that main.m as is doesn´t load any .xib. I have tried to modify it and put the `UIApplicationMain (argc,argv,nil,nil)` and stuff, but in that case i got my default .xib (with my PrjctViewController ) to load but i don´t get any response on the console. In that case there is no UDP connection at all.

How can i use UDPEcho sample to set a simple UDP "connection" with  some user interface? Something simple like the user being able to enter a ip and a port and getting some response from the device to be shown in the screen. The communication is not the problem, as i´m getting responses in the console, the whole problem is setting some simple interface while using this sample code. I don´t know how i can "override" main.m to load a .xib while maintaining my connection. I´ve already tried to pass all functions from main.m to my PrjctViewController but that doesn´t seem to solve my problem. If anybody has some example to show me or ideas to enlighten me up i´ll be very thankfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the connection stuff in one of the app launch, view controller init, or button event delegates.  Handle the connection asynchronously, or in a background thread, so as not to block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the connection stuff in main.m. Create your iPhone app as usual, and move the connection-creation code into a handler function for the user input. For instance, the user enters IP etc and clicks a 'Go' button. Put the connection setup into the handler for the 'Go' button instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I´m definitely using your approach, but now in a background thread to be able to refresh the UI..

Answer (score 0):

For future project take a look at [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

> CocoaAsyncSocket provides easy-to-use and powerful asynchronous socket libraries for Mac and iOS. The classes are described below.
>
> GCDAsyncUdpSocket and AsyncUdpSocket are UDP/IP socket networking libraries.